# redirect_uri mismatch for google oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, google-oauth

I am sorry this question has been asked many times, and I have seen multiple answers and cross checked with them, but no luck. Here is what the procedure I have followed

1) Went to google developer console
2) clicked create credentials
3) Oauth client id
4) Web appplication 
In the authorsied redirect uri's I gave `https://www.example.com/home`

I got the pop up of client id, client secret. Here I have added them

```
Spree::AuthenticationMethod.where(environment: Rails.env, provider: 'google_oauth2').first_or_create do |auth_method|
    auth_method.api_key = ENV['GOOGLE_ID']
    auth_method.api_secret = ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET']
    auth_method.active = true
  end
```

Now I am calling the google oauth using the following code

```
 <a href="https://www.example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2">
     <div>
       Sign up with google
     </div>
 </a>
```

Edit:

This is the error I am getting

```
The redirect URI in the request, https://www.example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/490969266456-ki43pu8ejosstkuv01jadmmmt1o33the.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=490969266456 to update the authorized redirect URIs.
```

Here is the request

```
Request Details
access_type=offline
scope=email
response_type=code
redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
state=31ad247324b285fdf6102e931707e041770a85990050eb40
client_id=490969266456-ki43pu8ejosstkuv01jadmmmt1o33the.apps.googleuserc
```

After seeing the above message
I went into the console, and updated the redirect uri to https://www.example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: yes heading is the error I am getting

Comment: Am I supposed to send the client id in the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem that happened was, I have created one account without proper redirection uri's. I had that in here

```
Spree::AuthenticationMethod.where(environment: Rails.env, provider: 'google_oauth2').first_or_create do |auth_method|
    auth_method.api_key = ENV['GOOGLE_ID']
    auth_method.api_secret = ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET']
    auth_method.active = true
  end
```

Later when I got to know, I had to put the proper callback url in the console, I created a new credentials. And updated them in the .env file.

But it did not seem to update them in Spree::AuthenticationMethod.all .. the previous keys were appearing. So I deleted those records and did the `rails s`.

The new keys, were appearing in rails console.

Another point to remember is

when you request like this 
href="https://www.example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2"> your  call back uri in the google console should be like this

https://www.example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback